# How do I reinstall the bioperl modules on Ubuntu?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am trying to learn bioinformatics the hard way. I have no background in Linux, Ubuntu, bash, Perl, Python, etc. I'm trying to use several programs, mostly the bioperl modules, that have been installed and used on this machine before.

It seems that older versions function but the newer ones don't. Specifically, it's the NCBI standalone blast group of programs. I can use `blastall`, but not `blastn`, `fastacmd`, or `blastdbcmd` even though those modules are present and show up as executable. The error I get is `no such file or dir`.

How do I uninstall this group of modules and then reinstall them? Or is there some other reason why they would not be found? I did try to run them from within the directory where they are located.

Comment: What do you see if you type `which <cmd>`, e.g. `which blastall` and `which blastn` in the terminal? If you have `sudo` privileges, you could try following [BioPerl's installation guide](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Installing_BioPerl_on_Ubuntu_Server) (after you run the `which` commands).

Answer (score 0):

They are not supposed to be used as standalone executables. See `man bastall` for details but, for example:

```
blastall -p blastn -i input.fa -d nr
```

will run a blastn search against the nr database using the fasta file `input.fa` as input. In general, to run any of these programs, you need to run

```
blastall -p PROGRAM_NAME
```

Oh, and these are not bioperl modules, they are standalone programs and have nothing to do with bioperl.